# Add a new element to the beginning of an existing cell array

Tags: matlab

I want to add an element into an existing 20x1 cell array so that the array becomes 21x1. I found a way to do add elements at the end from an answer to a previous question in the group

```
Q{end+1} = 'E1';
```

But how to do this at the beginning?

Comment: Please consider accepting the answer if it solved your problem. It's the check mark on the left side of the answer. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Luckily, concatenation works with cell arrays too:

First, let's create a dummy cell array `A` to use as example:

```
A = {1;2;'ABC';@(n)sin(n)}
A = 
    [       1]
    [       2]
    'ABC'     
    @(n)sin(n)
```

Now, let's concatenate it with `'E1'` using brackets:

```
A = ['E1'; A]
A = 
    'E1'      
    [       1]
    [       2]
    'ABC'     
    @(n)sin(n)
```

The more explicit alternative is [`vertcat`](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/vertcat.html) (vertical concatenation):

```
A = vertcat('E1', A)
A = 
    'E1'      
    [       1]
    [       2]
    'ABC'     
    @(n)sin(n)
```

Comment: You could.... use `fliplr` or `flipud`, add the element at the end, then flip back :D... lol. +1.

Comment: @rayryeng yeah, that's the second best way to do this... The best is a `while` loop!